# Error "main class not found"

Tags: java, classpath

All,

My classpath has been set to the following folder:

```
CLASSPATH = .;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\project
```

All my java files and class files are under `project` folder listed in `CLASSPATH`.

Yet I am getting the following error while running a `DriverClass` in `project` folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\project>java DriverClass
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DriverClass (wrong name: project/DriverClass)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: DriverClass.  Program will exit.
```

Can anyone please help me understand the reason here?

Comment: @user183717: did you set any package for this class? or just the default package?

Comment: yes the package is `project` . And I have included it in the CLASSPATH as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inside the package. You should be sitting in the package root. Go one folder up.

```
cd ..
```

Then reexecute it using `java project.DriverClass`.

---

That said, you should prefer not to use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. Yours is currently also invalid. There are spaces in unquoted pathnames. Also, the `JDK/bin` folder isn't supposed to go in the classpath. Just use the `-cp` argument like `java -cp . project.DriverClass` (while sitting in the package root folder).

Comment: Thank you so much BalusC. Can you please tell me the correct setup for environment variables after installing java. I am tired of spending too much time on this trivial thing

Comment: You're welcome. There are only 2 things: 1) full path to `JDK/bin` should be appended to OS-specific `%PATH%` environment variable so that you'll be able to execute `java.exe`, `javac.exe`, `javap.exe` and others from everywhere. As far now this looks already be properly setup. 2) full path to `JDK` (not `/bin`!) should go in `%JAVA_HOME%` environment variable. It's not necessary when you're still fiddling in command prompt, but most Java apps which require the JDK toolset (i.e. the compiler) are relying on this, e.g. Apache Tomcat webserver, Ant build tool, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin>java project.DriverClass
```

assuming your package is `project`

Comment: Try adding `-cp .` as BalusC said.

Answer (score 0):

After compiling if we get a main class not found error, It is simple try this
set classpath=%classpath%;.;
type this in cmd and run it..problem will be resolved